# How to access variable in a public method in Java?

Tags: java

```
public class Test(){
  public List makeList(){
    //some code
    ....
    double density = mass / vol;
    return mylist;
  }
}
```

How can I refer to `density` even though I only returned a list? In Python, I can call `self.density`

I know I can create another class `Pair<List, Double>` but I would rather not do that due to clutter.

Comment: "In Python I can call `self.density`". No you can't, not unless it's a member of the object `Test`.

Comment: The behaviour in Python and Java here are identical (assuming you're talking about a public field of the class)

Comment: Please see variable scope and life cycle for reference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> In Python, I can call self.density

No, this is not the same. What yo have defined in your code is a **local variable** - its scope is limited to `makeList()`.

If you want to refer to it from other methods, you can make it an instance variable (this is what you do with `self` in Python):

```
public class Test {
   private double density = 0.0;

   public List makeList(){
      //some code
      ....
      density = mass / vol;
      return mylist;
   }
}
```

Comment: You might want to fix `public class Test()` too (as [Manuel pointed out](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17784738/56285)).

Comment: @Jonik Thanks - been to focused on the scope related question :)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I only started learning Java recently.

Answer (score 3):

Make `density` an instance member of your `Test` class.

```
public class Test { // NO open/close parenthesis here!

  private double density;

  public List makeList() {
    //some code
    ....
    this.density = mass / vol;
    return mylist;
  }

  public double getDensity() {
    return this.density;
  }

}
```

Then call:

```
Test test = new Test();
List myList = test.makeList();
double density = test.getDensity();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare `density` as a member of the class `Test` outside the method and merely assign it within the method. If it is declared within the method, it can't be accessed elsewhere.

Like so:

```
public class Test{
     private double density;

     public List makeList(){
        //some code
        ....
        density = mass / vol;
        return mylist;
     }
}
```